# XSLT solo regresa etiquetas de cierre

Tags: xml, xsl, xslt, xml-schema

Tengo los siguientes archivos pero lo estoy testeando en:

> https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html

Pero me regresa mal el documento no funciona.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ExternalSeach>
    <Results>
        <Company>
            <CompanyName>wrer MEXICO, S.A. DE C.V. </CompanyName>
            <Address>
                <Street>Insur sdf</Street>
                <Colonia>Atlampa</Colonia>
                <Poblacion>Mexico, D.F.</Poblacion>
                <Country>México</Country>
                <State>Ciudad de México</State>
                <Municipio>Cuauhtémoc</Municipio>
                <PostalCode>06000</PostalCode>
                <IsoCountry>MEX</IsoCountry>
            </Address>
            <Identifiers>
                <legalIdentifiers>
                    <IdentifierName>RFC</IdentifierName>
                    <IdentifierValue>ATY-934507-34t</IdentifierValue>
                </legalIdentifiers>
                <Id>1629</Id>
            </Identifiers>
            <Phone>56565656</Phone>
            <FAX> </FAX>
        </Company>
    </Results>
</ExternalSeach>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>

    <body>
        <h2>
            <xsl:value-of select="CompanyName" />
        </h2>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="Street" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="Colonia" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="Poblacion" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="Country" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="State" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="Municipio" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="PostalCode" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="IsoCountry" />
        </p>
        <h3>Identifiers</h3>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="IdentifierName" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="IdentifierValue" />
        </p>
        <h4>Id ARCSA:
            <xsl:value-of select="Id" />
        </h4>
        <h3>Contact</h3>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="Phone" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="FAX" />
        </p>
    </body>

    </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema con la transformación que planteas es que estas refereciando tags sin tener en cuanta su ubicación dentro del XML:

Por ejemplo al querer traer:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="CompanyName" />
```

Debes indicar la ruta completa:

```
  <xsl:value-of select="ExternalSeach/Results/Company/CompanyName" />
```

Otra salida podría ser crear templates que te procesen secciones del XML por aparte donde
si puedas referenciarlos directamente

Ej:

```
<xsl:template match="Address>
       <p>
          <xsl:value-of select="Street" />
       </p>
</xsl:template>
```